# Flutter canvas drawing lines without overlay effect

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas, flutter-layout

In flutter canvas if you try to draw two lines one above the other on the overlap the result line becomes larger. Below the code and an image with the result.

```
class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawLine(const Offset(100, 100), const Offset(200, 200), Paint());
    canvas.drawLine(const Offset(100, 100), const Offset(400, 400), Paint());
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Line overlap

[image]

I hope it can be visible because the difference is very little.
In the project I'm working in, I don't want this to happen. Any suggestions?

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you referring top part is bold ?

Comment: Hi, you are right.

Comment: what is your expected  result

Comment: Basically, I expect that in the part where the two lines overlap you will not see this part in bold, but simply a straight and uniform line. Thank you

Comment: could be overlap color makes it bold, you can change the start point on that case

Comment: Yes, of course but this is only an example. In my project I have a lot of drawings that in some parts overlap and you see some bold lines and some not...